# Nested if - proceed to elif upon meeting a condition in the nested if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, control-flow

My question is on control flows with if-statements and arrays, basically, I am extracting some information to an array x (given conditions a,b) and the flow gets executed depending on whether there is some information extracted or there was no information. My code looks like that:

```
if a:
   x = ...
   if not x:
      if b: #repeated
         x = ...
         if not x:
            raise Exception
elif b: #repeated
         x = ...
         if not x:
            raise Exception
```

Is there any elegant way to skip to elif condition automatically after 'if not x'?
My primary focus is on a, if a is not present or doesn't contain any information, I am checking existence of b and whether it's empty. If b empty I am raising an exception (here i might actually proceed to else: raise Exception however it's the same thing as above and I don't know how to control such a flow i.e. redirect to another statement).

I've tried 'break' however it doesn't work for statements not nested in the for/while loops.

Thanks in advance!

**Some clarification based on comments**:

1. x gets assigned to an xmltree element and the element is different for a and b,
2. The 'if a' is about checking if item1 is present in an array, then I am checking if the element in xml tree assigned to it contains some information, if not I fall back on the default option b, and also checking if item2 now exists and if it contains information; if none of the abovementioned cases - the program should exit at this point

Comment: In some others programming languages they would have solved this using goto labels... anyway I'm going to follow this question, I don't know any solution to your problem... +1

Comment: maybe if you're more explicit about your problem a solution could come. but it's not clear at all. can you put some example?

Comment: The x = ... is always the same?

Comment: The code here seems too contrived and hypothetical to really offer a reasonable solution. Chances are, there is some better design for approaching whatever app or component/module you're writing that would avoid much of this deeply-nested control flow from the get-go. But it's not really clear what the use case is. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Comment: You should put the code you want to skip to (i.e. the Exception handling) in its own function, then call that function each time you wish to go there. Otherwise the unrecommended way to do this would be with "goto" functionality: http://entrian.com/goto/

Comment: @daniboy000 x is the assignment to an xml tree element, it's different for a and b, for a I am setting say x = file.getElementsByTagName('tagA'), for b:  x = file.getElementsByTagName('tagB')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the assignment to `x` is the same (or at least varies only in the value `a` or `b` used, you can use a loop with an `else` clause:

```
for thing in [a,b]:
    if not thing:
        continue
    x = ...  # can depend on thing
    if x:
        break
else:
    raise Exception
```

The `else` clause is only executed if the loop terminates due to exhaustion of the iterable, not if a `break` statement is executed.

Comment: I would like to avoid the usage of for loop, is there any possible solution without it?

Comment: Why? This situation seems to cry out for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is limited context I can only imagine what you want. If you use python 3.10, you might be able to use the `match` statement for your use case. Here's what I imagine this could look like but we can refurbish this further in the comments:

```py
class XMLNode:

    def __init__(self, subnode, label):
        self.subnode = subnode
        self.label = label

node = ...

match node
    case XMLNode(subnode=a, label=_):
        pass
    case XMLNode(subnode=b, label=_):
        pass
```